# Subbing in numbers to a set of solved simultaneous equations

Tags: equation-solving, export

I have the following set of equations (a,b,c) which all depend on some value x. The equations are defined in terms of 3 variables (d,e,f). I can solve the equations to find expressions for d, e and f in terms of a, b and c. I would now like to sub in multiple values of x, obtain values of a, b and c then use these to evaluate d, e and f. I hope this makes sense.

Please can someone tell me how to do this and then save the data in a csv with columns, x, a, b, c , d, e and f. Thanks very much for the help.

```
Clear[x, a, b, c]
xvals := Subdivide[1, 10, 9]
a[x_] := 2*x + 1 b[x_] := x + 3
c[x_] := 3*x - 4
Solve[a == d + e + f && b == 2*d*e + f && c == 2*e - f, {d, e, f}]
```

Comment: Post your code in a code block so people can copy and paste it - don't post images of code.

Comment: Use various forms of ``ReplaceAll` to insert definitions of `a,b,c` into your solutions and then use Table or similar functions to evaluate your solutions for many specific values of `x`.  There are may ways to accomplish what you are seeking.  Check the documentation.

Comment: Block of my code: Clear[x, a, b, c]
xvals :=  Subdivide[1, 10, 9]
a[x_] := 2*x + 1
b[x_] := x + 3
c[x_] := 3*x - 4
Solve[a == d + e + f &&
  b == 2*d*e + f &&
  c == 2*e - f,
 {d, e, f}]

Comment: I have edited your post to include the code in the post.  In the future, you can do this yourself by hitting the grey Edit button below your post.  Indent code block lines by four spaces, and they will appear as above.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[x, a, b, c, d, e, f];

a = 2*x + 1;
b = x + 3;
c = 3*x - 4;
xvals = Subdivide[1, 10, 9];

sol = Solve[a == d + e + f && b == 2*d*e + f && c == 2*e - f, {d, e, f}]
```

For the first solution

```
Table[{x, a, b, c, Flatten[{d, e, f} /. sol[[1]]]}, {x, xvals}] // Map[Flatten]
```

Prepend column headers to the above and `Export` to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
xvals := Range[10];
a[x_] := 2*x + 1 ;
b[x_] := x + 3;
c[x_] := 3*x - 4;
sol = Solve[
  a[x] == d + e + f && b[x] == 2*d*e + f && c[x] == 2*e - f, {d, e, f}]

{{d -> 1/2 (-4 + 5 x + Sqrt[10 - 44 x + 25 x^2]), 
  e -> 1/6 (-2 + 5 x - Sqrt[10 - 44 x + 25 x^2]), 
  f -> 1/3 (10 - 4 x - Sqrt[10 - 44 x + 25 x^2])}, {d -> 
   1/2 (-4 + 5 x - Sqrt[10 - 44 x + 25 x^2]), 
  e -> 1/6 (-2 + 5 x + Sqrt[10 - 44 x + 25 x^2]), 
  f -> 1/3 (10 - 4 x + Sqrt[10 - 44 x + 25 x^2])}}

(table = (Prepend[
     Table[{xv, a[xv], b[xv], c[xv], {d, e, f} /. sol /. x -> N[xv]} //
        Flatten, {xv, xvals}], {"x", "a[x]", "b[x]", "c[x]", "d1[x]", 
      "e1[x]", "f1[x]", "d2[x]", "e2[x]", "f2[x]"}])) // 
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

```
Export["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/table.csv", table]

(* "/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/table.csv" *)
```